# Implementing a localisable string in IOS with hyperlink

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilabel

I am building an app, and would like to create this feature.

> "By using our services, you agree to our terms of service"`

This `label/text` should also be localisable in Japanese and German,

and when the user clicks on *`Terms of Service`*, the app should launch a `webview` to an external website.

I've tried `UILabel` and `ActiveLabel`, but they don't seem to be able to localise/translate.

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks and appreciated.

Comment: Have you added localisable file for japanese and german?

Comment: May be they only provide a hyperlink text. You have to handle localization yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried UILabel and ActiveLabel, but they don't seem to be able to
>   localise/translate.

`ActiveLabel` is merely a subclass of `UILabel` and I use it the same case with you for a tappable labels that opens up a `UIWebView`, therefore you can just pass a localised string to your activeLabel object easily.

For more information on how to do localisation, there are tons of resources here on Stackoverflow, Youtube, and Google.

Sample: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IV1x9FgQ5v0